# CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED non-functional in xcode5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5, core-foundation

The WWDC 2013 lecture slides contain a section that in some cases the explicit bridging casts can be omitted.  I wrote this in Xcode 5 (using 10.8 though, not 10.9), and the compiler complains I need a bridging cast.  Am I just totally not understanding the concept?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
CFStringRef MyCreateStringFromNothing();
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED

void SomeFunction() {
    // compiler requires bridging cast here...
    NSString* x = MyCreateStringFromNothing();    
}
```

The reason I ask is I wanted to write:

```
NSString* s = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
```

and thought that the new work on implicit bridging should simply enable me to write this.  But this also needs a bridging cast.

Comment: When you say "using 10.8", can you be more specific? There's three things at play: the OS you're running, the SDK, and the deployment target

Comment: I get the same results whether Xcode is running on 10.8, or 10.9.  Additionally, if the deployment target is ios7 or 10.9, also the same results.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be sort of black magic, but from my experiments functions with "Create" in them don't work with implicit bridging.

When I compiled this:

```
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
CFStringRef MyCreateStringFromNothing();
CFStringRef MyGetStringFromNothing();
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED

void SomeFunction() {
    NSString *const fails1 = MyCreateStringFromNothing();
    NSString *const fails2 = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("FOO"));

    NSString *const works = MyGetStringFromNothing();
}
```

The first two fail but the third one "works."

Note that implicit bridging apparently STILL does NOT actually keep the compiler from warning you about converting CFStringRef to NSString *, it just stops requiring you to insert a __bridge as well.

You'll notice that in slide at WWDC2013 in session 404 at 50:30, he uses CFDictionaryGetValue(), which returns a "void *", so it's one of the few functions that won't raise a warning. Any of the CF functions that return an actual type (e.g. CFStringRef, or CFDictionary) are still going to throw warnings, so, meh.

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler settings on the project and/or target.  If this is an older project, you might have a stray option there causing you to use an older compiler.  (This tripped me up a few times  when I moved to Xcode 5  and  wanted to use the latest Obj-C newness.)

These days, I always  choose  "Default compiler" in my build options.